# Inconsistencies in search results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, elgg

I am making a query against Elgg database. Here is the database overview about Elgg http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel

```
            SELECT DISTINCT e. * 
                FROM elgg_entities e
                    JOIN elgg_metadata n_table ON e.guid = n_table.entity_guid
                    JOIN elgg_metastrings msn ON n_table.name_id = msn.id
                    JOIN elgg_users_entity ue ON e.guid = ue.guid
                    JOIN elgg_metadata md ON e.guid = md.entity_guid
                    JOIN elgg_metastrings msv ON n_table.value_id = msv.id
                WHERE (
                        (
                            (
                                MATCH (
                                    ue.username, ue.name
                                )
                                AGAINST (
                                     '+gastro +surgeon'
                                    IN BOOLEAN
                                    MODE
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        OR (
                            (
                                (
                                    (
                                        (
                                            (
                                                msn.string
                                                IN (
                                                 'breifdescription'
                                                )
                                            )
                                            AND (
                                            ( 1 =1 ) 
                                            AND (
                                                n_table.enabled =  'yes'
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                AND msv.string LIKE  '%gastro surgeon%'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                        (
                            e.type =  'user'
                        )
                    )
                AND (
                        e.site_guid
                        IN ( 1 )
                    )
                AND (
                    ( 1 =1 ) 
                    AND (
                        e.enabled =  'yes'
                    )
                )
                LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But this is returning no search results where as a simple search query like below is working

```
            SELECT * 
            FROM  `elgg_metastrings` 
            WHERE  `string` LIKE  '%gastro surgeon%'
            LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The same query is working fine if the searched string is having only one word like surgeon, physician etc.. the query fails when it have more than one word.

Tried a lot to debug it. But no success. Anybody have an idea on why the first query fails?

Comment: I would startfrom removing part by part from WHERE to figure out which exactly condition excludes results. Then figure out why.

Comment: it could be related to ft_min_word_len  in mysql. Check the length specified in mysql config. In linux its usually in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, change the value restart the mysql server and then drop the index and create index or repair the table, this should fix it.